# Geometry nodes: Why does it take a slightly different align-euler-to-vector input when aligning something before realizing instances compared to after

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, vector

I instance a cube on a circle and want to align the cube to the circle normals **after** realizing the instances. I found a solution using this nodelogic:[image]

Why do I have to do this weird vector substraction (align euler z - align euler x)? Because if I don't do this the cubes rotate unexpectedly: [image]

Afterall, if you use the "simple" solution of just rotating the instances you only need 1 align to *Euler* node and both cases use the same circle normals?

[image]

Comment: I didnt really look further into this exact problem but i think it was due to the ring that carries the instances beeing rotated by 90°. If one applies the rotation in object mode this weird beviour should dissapear